# How to repeatedly prompt users to download figures?

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, download, jupyter

To preface, I'm not exactly a professional developer, but I have taken a couple programming courses (Python, Java, C++). I recently started working in a position which requires me to use Python (especially Jupyter notebooks, if that matters) regularly.

The program on which I'm working outputs some figures. I thought it would be great if the user could choose to save each figure as a png. It would be really cool if there was a final option to save all figures once the rest of the program was done running. I don't quite know where to start. For loop? Recursion?

I wrote one bit that asks the user if they want to save a specific figure, then executes the download if the user inputs yes:

```
save_x_plot = input("Would you like to save this figure?")

yeses = 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES'

if save_x_plot in yeses:
    plt.savefig('x_plot.png',dpi=100,bbox_inches='tight')
    
else:
    print("Ok :(")
```

This works fine, and I could stick that block of code in front of each plt.savefig(), but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You could easily append the data needed for storage to a list of dictionaries and at the end of the program execution, loop over the built list of dicts to save them so it isn't saved after each question

Comment: How about putting a cell at the end of the notebook that iterates over `plt.get_fignums()` and prompts and/or saves each one?

Comment: Note that users can already save individual images by just right clicking and saving the image. It's running in the browser, after all. If you want a "save all images" you almost certainly want to have a look at how to create a zip file purely in python, so you can create a single file containing all the images, and then look up how to make a notebook trigger a download for that file.